# cordova 3.1.0 application how to put a slideshow before the application starts?

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I want to know how to put a slideshow depicting the working of an application or how to use the application on the start of the app ? I wanna launch this app for both ios and android.....
Thanks in advance 
Regards 
Nick

Comment: Create a video and play it...

Comment: I wanna create a swipe slideshow there, not a video

Comment: So make use of jquery swipe [plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/mobile-devices/5-jquery-touch-swipe-image-gallery-plugins/)

Comment: Thanks for the plugin link but I want to know how to put the slideshow on start of application (before the actual application runs)